# Write codes for foreign keys of this db (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

My db structure is as below and I also have some data. How do I specify foreign keys using the MyIASM engine?

I have read the MySQL webisite, but because I am afraid of making errors I am asking you to show me an example.

- one article can belong to many categories.
- one article can have zero or many photos.
- one article can have zero or many tags.

My db structure:

```
tb_categories|cat_id(pk) , catname , parent_id
tb_articles|article_id(pk) , title , subtitle , textbody ,  date , remark
tb_articles_categories|id(PK) article_id(fk) , cat_id(fk)
tb_phptos|photo_id(pk) , photofilename , article_id(fk)
tb_articles_photo|article_id(fk) , photo_id(fk)
tb_tags|tag_id(pk) , tagname
tb_articles_tags|id(PK) article_id(fk) , tag_id(fk)
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this yourself? Have a go first and if it doesn't work, ask a specific question.

Comment: If you're afraid of making errors while trying, create a backup copy of your databsae and do tests using this copy. Remember this rule, and it will save your back-end many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM does not support foreign key constraints, so you don't.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM does not support foreign keys. Only InnoDB does.